# Angular scope not updating to factory value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a very simple factory

```
angular.module('vpmClient')

.factory('DatosFactory', function($http){
    var datos = {};
    datos.data = [];

    datos.getDatos = function(){
        $http.post('php/dataHandler.php',{action:"get_datos"}).success(function(data){
            datos.data = data;
        });
    };

    datos.getDatos();

    return datos;
})
```

And in the Controller i set the value from "datos.data" to a scope variable

```
angular.module('vpmClient')

.controller('DatosController', function($http,$scope,DatosFactory){
    $scope.datos = DatosFactory.data;
    $scope.datoSeleccionado = {};

    $scope.getDatos = function(){
        console.log(DatosFactory.data);
        return DatosFactory.data;
    }

    $scope.mostrarDato = function(dato){
        //$scope.datoSeleccionado = dato;
        //Magia
    }
});
```

I need that the value of "scope.datos" updates once the post from the factory ends

Notes: I did a console.log from the factory (inside the success) and it gives me the Object correctly, also, in the controller i created a function to return the factory's value from the browser console and it also works, but when i console.log "scope.datos" it returns an empty object.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: When do you see the empty console.log ? Where did you place it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the promise from $http to the controller

```
angular.module('vpmClient').factory('DatosFactory', function($http){
var datos = {};
datos.data = [];

datos.getDatos = function(){
    return $http.post('php/dataHandler.php',{action:"get_datos"});
};

return datos;
})
```

And in the controller you call the service

```
angular.module('vpmClient').controller('DatosController', function($http,$scope,DatosFactory){



$scope.datos = DatosFactory.data;
$scope.datoSeleccionado = {};

$scope.getDatos = function(){
  DatosFactory.getDatos()
  .then(function(httpResponse){
    console.log(httpResponse.data);
    $scope.datoSeleccionado = httpResponse.data;
  })
}
});
```

Comment: This one's correct approach..also `then` or `success` can be used. OP you were accessing var before post is completed.

Comment: I like 'then' more. Just for the looks :)

Comment: sure.. thats whay +1. but that was for OP, if he/she wanted to use `success` as using previously.

Comment: I already solved it with $scope.datos = DatosFactory; and in the ng-repeat in the html datos.data. But your answer works perfectly so it's an accepted question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `then` keyword:

```
$scope.getDatos = function() {
    DatosFactory.getDatos().then(function(data) {
        $scope.datos = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: $scope.getDatos it's the function i use to check from the browser console, it's never executed